# linux pointers and references and methods

Tags: c++, linux

Sorry for destrubing. I have a problem:

```
file.h

#include <string>
class X
{
public:
    X();
    class Y
    {
    public:
        Y();
        std::string name;
    }*yy;
    std::string method(X::Y *Y);
}*xx;
```

file.cpp

```
#include "file.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
X::X()
{
    yy= new X::Y();
}
X::Y::Y()
{
    cout<<name<<endl;
}
std::string X::method(X::Y *Y)
{
    return (Y->name);
}
extern "C" C* create_object(){ return new X;}
```

And now I have a test.cpp file. I create an .so file from file.cpp and file.h 
in test.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    void* handle= dlopen("file.so",RTLD_NOW);
    X* (*create)();
    void (*destroy)(X*);

    create = (X*(*))dlsym(handle,"create_obj");
    destroy = (void(*)(X*))dlsym(handle,"destory_obj");

    X::Y* (*create1)();
    void (*destroy1)(X::Y*);

    create1 = (X::Y*(*))dlsym(handle,"create_obj");
    destroy1 = (void(*)(X::Y*))dlsym(handle,"destory_obj");

    X* fir = (X*)(create);
    X:Y* tt = (X::Y*)create1();
    tt->name="me";
    fir->method(&tt); //I WANT TO SEND A REFERENCE TO THE X::Y object class. It is not working.
    //No match function to call to "XX::method(XX::YY**); WHY. Can someone help me? THX

    destroy(fir);
    destroy(tt);
}
```

Comment: You should really start off by giving meaningful names to variables, clases & methods!

Comment: How are `create_obj` and `destroy_obj` defined? BTW in your code there is a typo `"destory_obj"` that should probably be `"destroy_obj"`.

Comment: create_obs and detroy_obj are not defined.

Comment: @linuxx: I just noticed that you already asked more than twenty questions here on SO, each of them obtaining several answers, and yet you did not cast a single vote. When someone gives you an answer that is useful, you should *upvote* it, meaning clicking the litte triangle pointing up on the left of their answer. This will reward their efforts by giving them reputation. You can also choose one answer per question and mark it as accepted (the tick on the left of the answer), to indicate that it is the best answer and that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type `fir->method(&tt);` you pass the address of `tt`, which is a pointer. So you're passing a *pointer to a pointer*.

What you want to do is `fir->method(*tt);`. Which will in fact pass your pointed object as a reference (because "converting" a *pointer* to a *reference* is done by "dereferencing" the pointer). This implies that you change `std::string method(X::Y *Y);` with `std::string method(X::Y &Y);` in declaration and implementation. It means that whenever you pass an Y to your function, it will be in fact passed as reference and not value. It also means you have to access Y members with `.` and not `->`.

Comment: I would like to pass the reference. Not the pointer! How to do that?I need to pass the reference. This is just a part from the classes. Can you please help me>

Comment: It is not working. It says: no match function for call X:method(X::Y&);

Comment: why?Can you please explain? WIll it work? How should I change return Y->name? with &(Y->name)?

Comment: @linuxx: Sorry, but if you don't recognize declaration of method accepting a pointer from declaration of method accepting a reference, you should start by reading some book on C++, [like this one online (section 3.3 talks about references)](http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/)

Comment: I did replace the *Y with &Y but it's not working. In the file.cpp I can't have in the method(XX::YY &Y) return Y->name (error:base operand of -> has non-pointer type). PLease help:).

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will try it:) THANK YOU ONE MORE TIME! I will change the Y->name with Y.name. In the test.cpp if i send through reference the tt object in method((&tt) it will change the name from the Y object in all the methods where I use Y.name (in file.cpp),no?

Comment: In the test.cpp I have fir->method(*tt) , but when i compile it i have the error: undefined reference to X::method(X:Y&). :((...I COMPILE WITH g++ test.cpp -o -ldl test